# Genymotion resets VirtualBox networking to "Host-only Ethernet Adapter"

Tags: networking, virtualbox

After some (VMWare) deinstallations Genymotion virtual machine can't access Internet.

In VirtualBox networking settings there is "VirtualBox Host-only Ethernet adapter set".

Ok, I change the adapter to: network bridge, but as soon as I start virtual machine using Genymotion, it resets network adapter back to host-only adapter and even writes a quick message in a dialog about that.

How to restore normal networking in Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for someone stumbles upon this question: "VirtualBox Host-only Ethernet" is Genymotion's adapter for remote adb to the virtual machine. If you want to change the VM's network interface, use the second one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot check and accept your answer because I am not working with Genymotion long ago.