# How does Genymotion bypass VirtualBox' lack of Wi-Fi emulation?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox

As [answered here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209604/147973), VirtualBox doesn't know how to emulate Wi-Fi. It can connect a guest into the host's Wi-Fi, but the guest will still think the connection is one of "[up to eight virtual PCI Ethernet cards](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)".

But Genymotion, which is a wrapper on top of VirtualBox, [does manage to do it](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#network-configuration). Is there something to do inside VirtualBox that will replicate what Genymotion does and open an emulated Wi-Fi option?

It might seem redundant to use Genymotion on top of VirtualBox just for this one supposedly basic feature.

I do have one theory even if it might be far fetched. According to online searches, VirtualBox allows connecting USB Wi-Fi dongles into the guest. Could it be Genymotion found a way to fake a USB Wi-Fi dongle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how Genymotion does it but I know how it can be done. I've seen several products like Genymotion that implemented this feature.

There are basically 3 methods in theory of doing this:

1. Use PCI pass-though to pass the Wifi NIC through to the guest, in the same way that VirtualBox can pass USB devices through. This is VERY unlikely as this method is quite difficult and will not work with the majority of hardware. (VirtualBox itself, although it has supported PCI pass-through for years, still considers this "experimental".) And, like with USB pass-though, the Wifi NIC is not longer available to the host-system.
2. There is already a special interface path between the host and the guest. VirtualBox uses this e.g. for synchronising display-size changes from guest to host, shared clipboard and to implement the virtual file-system. You could extend this to also send the extra information between host and guest needed to piggy-back the guests Wifi handling to the host. It would be very complicated to use this method though, because keeping the Wifi meta-data and the actual network-traffic in sync would be very difficult as they would follow totally different data-paths.
3. The method I've seen used by all similar products: Replace the VirtualBox guest network-driver and the VirtualBox host-side network-bridge devices with modified versions that not only pass-through the network-traffic but also the Wifi additions (such as SSID handling, network discovery, authentication, etc.)
   Genymotion seems to use this method too. I just noticed there is another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/874080/genymotion-resets-virtualbox-networking-to-host-only-ethernet-adapter?rq=1) on this site regarding Genymotion modifying the host bridge-drivers configuration, which seems to imply they use that in some way.

Unfortunately I don't know of any free (or cheap) implementations for this. I could definitely use it myself.

Comment: That was impressive and quick! But just to clarify, do you refer to passthrough? Genymotion doesn't even care if the host has Wi-Fi or not, and that's exactly the case that interests me. No different than how the host can use Wi-Fi while the guest thinks it's Ethernet.

Comment: @LWC You didn't mention that the host doesn't have to have Wifi, but that actually doesn't matter. It uses the 3rd method I described. The guest OS believes whatever the fake Wifi driver is saying. It has no way of knowing that it is a real piece of hardware or an emulated Wifi card (and emulated Wifi network) the driver is representing. What it all comes down to is that the Genymotion supplied drivers in the guest OS just lie. In exactly the same way that the normal Vbox network drivers lie about what network hardware they represent when you map them to a real Wifi card on the host.

Comment: If only VirtualBox cared to do it on their own without being hacked...